# JasperReports Server using REST with JSON request return PDF report

Tags: json, rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to export reports in PDF from my app (Writed in MEAN) sending data to fill the report through the request.

It is possible to call JasperReports Server REST with a JSON file as a DataSource returning PDF report as output?

I found some examples using external datasource as JSON, but not sending JSON in request.

Comment: Please check this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408863/location-data-for-filling-the-report-in-jasperserver/37441567#37441567. It contains some basic samples on how to pass XML and JSON to a JasperReports Server instance via REST services.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks.  it Works !! =)