# Jasperserver Data Source From Remote Json

Tags: json, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm trying generate report from jasperserver sending as a parameter Json URL from data.
In my local environment jasperstudio, i have created a data adapter, and associated with the report, but after publish the report i don't know how i can change the source on remote for generate it.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Start from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37441567/5292302) by Narcis on the post linked, if you still have doubt either edit this to narrow down your issue (and ping me, I can reopen it) or create a new question.

Comment: Very nice! I understand the concepts and make it work.