# How to use array as a parameter in JasperStudio?

Tags: jasper-reports

I was tryong to send a collection of arrays from Laravel_10 Controller to JasperStudio using PHP_8 and want to access them there. The collection was this,

`{"main_unit":["CARTON","carton"],"main_unit_qty":[2.4,6.8],"unit":["PCS"],"qty":[102]}`

I created a parameter in JasperStudio with a name "table_totals" as string" and tried to access it there like this,

`$P(table_totals).main_unit[0]`

but it's not working. I also tried to set type of parameter to OBJECT by hard coating it in the XML file, but it's still not working.
Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37441567/5882963